# How to import a module into another module in databricks notebook?

Tags: python, module, databricks

This is my config.py in Databricks

```
DATA_S3_LOCATION='s3://server-data/data1'
DATA_S3_FILE_TYPE='orc'
DATA2_S3_LOCATION='s3://server-data/data2'
DATA2_S3_FILE_TYPE='orc'
```

I have **init** . py in this folder as well

I am trying to access these variables in another file

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/Users/file')
from file import config
```

I am facing error , no module named file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several aspects here.

- If these files are notebooks, then you need to use `%run ./config` to include notebook from the current directory ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#run))
- if you're using [Databricks Repos](https://docs.databricks.com/repos/index.html) and arbitrary files support is enabled, then your code needs to be a Python file, not notebook, and have correct directory layout with `__init__.py`, etc.  In this case, you can use Python imports. Your repository directory will be automatically added into a `sys.path` and you don't need to modify it.

P.S. I have an [example](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo) of repository with both notebooks & Python files approaches.

Comment: Looks like the behaviour in Workspace is totally different then repos

Comment: yes, but workspace approach works for both Repos & workspace, but import of files as packages works only in Repos

Comment: It works, but I noticed that you have to detach and re-attach a notebook from the cluster when you make changes to modules. Not really convenient if you ask me.

Comment: No, you don't need to re-attach for that, but you need to put two magic commands for auto-reload: https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/blob/master/unit-tests/test_with_arbitrary_files.py#L6